# Writing image to response in ASP .NET results in "OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used."

Tags: c#, asp.net

we have been running an ASP .NET (without MVC) application for years without any problems. However, we have now changed the server and now we get the following error:

> **OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used.**
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used.]
>      System.Web.HttpResponse.BinaryWrite(Byte[] buffer) +4840090
>      App.Loader.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +3464

See my code below:

```
public partial class Loader : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        var filePath = @"C:\test\testfile.jpg";

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

I have noticted that the error occurs as soon as the property OutputStream from Response object is accessed.
I have found a lot of similar problems here and in the web but I am afraid those are always in an context of an mvc application.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution now.
I am running the cms system umbraco with this application and its new version uses the MVC framework as underlying framework. Therefore, I suppose that the Response object was somehow not valid any more.